# Prove this set is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets from $\Omega$ and let $\Omega_0\subseteq \Omega$. Prove that $\mathcal{F}\cap\Omega_0:=\{F\cap\Omega_0 | F\in\mathcal{F}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets from $\Omega_0$.

My only problem is with the complements:

Let $F\cap\Omega_0 \in \mathcal{F}\cap\Omega_0$ so $(F\cap\Omega_0)^c=F^c\cup\Omega_0^c$ and so I don't know how to show it as an intersection with $\Omega_0$

Comment: Does it hold for sigma algebra of the type $\mathcal{F} = \{\varnothing, \Omega\}$?

Comment: Actually yes, doesn't it? $\mathcal{F}\cap\Omega_0=\{\varnothing, \Omega_0\}$, so $\varnothing \in \mathcal{F}\cap\Omega_0$, for the argument of carmichael561, $\varnothing^c=\Omega_0$ and vice versa and any countable union of $\varnothing, \Omega_0$ will remain in the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you restrict to $\Omega_0$, everything is happening inside this set. So for the complement you should consider $\Omega_0\setminus F=F^c\cap\Omega_0$ rather than $(F\cap\Omega_0)^c$.

Comment: Cool, thanks! :)